# 500 Internal server error in express.js while executing HTTP POST request using AJAX client-side

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, express

Recieving a 500 Internal Server Error while sending an HTTP POST request to the server from the client side javascript using JQuery AJAX in Express.js.
This is the p.js file running on client-side.

```
    function dataHandler(conn,data)
    {
       var datalol=data;
       console.log(datalol);
      dataString={"data":datalol};
      $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:window.location.href+'recieve/',
        data:JSON.stringify(dataString),
        dataType:'json'
      }).done(function(data){

        console.log(data);
      }).fail(function(error,jqXHR,textStatus){
          console.log(error);
          console.log(jqXHR);
          console.log(textStatus);
      });

    }
```

the index.js file running on the server.

```
    router.post('/recieve',(req,res) => {
        var json1=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body.data));
        console.log(json1);
        var json2=JSON.parse(json1.data);
        console.log(json2);
        var newblock=new Block(json2[0].index,json2[0].previousHash,json2[0].timestamp, json2[0].data, json2[0].hash);
        addBlock(newblock);
        res.send("Success");
    });
```

Comment: Dude 500 can mean a lot of things, are you getting both the console.log? If yes there's something wrong with your newblock code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution at this link (https://gist.github.com/diorahman/1520485). I have no idea why but replacing dataType with contentType:"application/json" solved the problem.